# What is the effect of IntendedUse in AWS Location Place Index resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, esri

I'm implementing an address suggestions solution using the [AWS Location](https://aws.amazon.com/location/) service.

On the `Place Index` resource, there is an `IntendedUse` property that takes either `SingleUse` (default) or `Storage` (See the [CloudFormation definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-location-placeindex-datasourceconfiguration.html)).

From the description in the CloudFormation doco above, it sounds like if I intend to store or cache results, I should use `Storage`. Since I intend to eventually store results of Place Index functions I chose storage with the Esri data provider.

However, once I did this and called the `SearchPlaceIndexForSuggestions` function I received a validation error:

```
{
  "errorType": "ValidationException",
  "errorMessage": "PlaceIndex [redacted] cannot be used for SearchPlaceIndexForSuggestions because it has IntendedUse Storage",
  ...
}
```

Following this, I don't really understand the purpose of this property or if it has any practical effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't speak on behalf of AWS, but from my digging this is what I found.

From [AWS Terms of Use](https://aws.amazon.com/service-terms/), you **must** indicate `IntendedUse` as `Storage` if you are going to store the data (emphasis mine).

> 82.3 You may not:
>
> e. Store or cache Location Data, **except** (i) for geocoding and reverse-geocoding results (other than as prohibited in Section 82.4.a) **when you indicate the result will be stored in the API parameter** or (ii) to comply with legal, regulatory, or reasonable internal record-keeping requirements.

Reading the other terms for this service, you can feel that *they are very concerned* about customers using their location services as a means to offer their own location services. So from this perspective, it makes sense that they require you to declare your **intent** of storing the data. Keeping this in mind, if you think about the parameter name `IntendedUse`, it sounds a lot like a legal declaration rather than a technical configuration.

Furthermore, the [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/location/pricing/) for API with `stored results` is 8x more expensive.

> Addresses geocoded    $0.50 per 1,000
>
> Addresses geocoded (stored results)   $4.00 per 1,000

So, to answer your question if this parameter has a purpose at all, it seems it does have a significant purpose legally and financially. Certainly not what I expected, but all evidences I found point to this conclusion.

And again disclaimer: I don't speak on behalf of AWS.

Comment: Amazing find, and very good to know about the pricing!

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: I am not a certified or trained legal expert. THIS IS NOT LEGAL ADVICE. DO NOT USE IT. I am simply a developer trying to figure out their terms of service for myself. Hopefully something in my thought process will help you here. If anyone from AWS can take this into consideration and hopefully clarify the documentation, I would be grateful.

First, defining my terms. Hopefully I'm mostly consistent here.

- "Customer" is the AWS customer using autocomplete to improve a user's experience.
- "User" means the user using the customer's service and hopefully benefitting from autocomplete.

Secondly, everything in this answer is specifically focused on why `SearchPlaceIndexForSuggestions` only allows a single-use index, and the logic would apply equally to the Place_ID and the Text.

---

According to 82.3, "For Geolocation Providers other than Open Data, you may not":

"e. Store or cache Location Data, except "

- (i) for geocoding and reverse-geocoding results when you indicate the result will be stored in the API parameter

  - See Section 82.4.a for an exception to this exception.
- or (ii) to comply with legal, regulatory, or reasonable internal record-keeping requirements.

There is no exception for when you indicate the result will not be stored, so you are not allowed to store it unless you indicate that it will be stored.

---

"But I'm storing the address lookup result in my database to keep track of it! That's the point of *autocomplete*!", I can hear you say!

It's unfortunate that this use case is not explained better for technical experts like us, but I'm going to logically conclude that if you cannot store the result of a lookup, then they would not call it *autocomplete*, so that must mean that they are worried about you storing the *connection* between the request and the result, *not* about storing the final result (otherwise there is no point in AWS even offering the service if you can't use the results for anything).

Either implement your own fuzzy search algorithm using the other parts of the service that *can* be stored, or just pass the request through to their fuzzy search algorithm. Caching the result of a fuzzy search and serving those results identically for future autocomplete requests can quickly result in many of software's worst nightmares.

This is also implied by the term "single-use", where the customer uses the result returned from a request for one use, and then the next time a user types in that exact string the customer again calls AWS in case they get a different response, rather than assuming it will be the same. So a single-use input string may be stored alongside the resulting data "for record keeping purposes" such as logging or audits (or user complaints), but may not be used for looking up that same search result again the next time a user types in a request.

- It's reasonable to give the user a history of their searches and corresponding results in case they want to go back to a specific result which they typed in and then moved on from, because that qualifies as a single-use (the user wants *that* search result that got returned *that* time by the fuzzy algorithm). The customer is not returning an old search result for a new query, they're simply keeping a record for the user's benefit.

This conclusion is also supported by 82.3a. "[You may not] Scrape, systematically collect, or duplicate the data provided to you from Amazon Location Service (e.g., map tiles, forward and reverse geocodes, routes, drive times/isochrones, and other data) (collectively, “Location Data”), **including for the purpose of avoiding use of Amazon Location Service**." (emphasis mine)

It is reasonable to conclude that they are attempting to protect their continued effort to improve the data. In the case here of fuzzy search suggestions, they also require a human to actually choose the desired address since that is the supported use case. As any technical expert can testify, trying to solve the headaches of an unintended use case can be a nightmare.

In short, single-use means you hit their server every single time you want to lookup an address, for multiple (very justifiable) reasons.

1. Money = mouths to feed. If you cannot feed your employees they won't work for you and you won't be able to offer the service any more. So they don't want you to take their work and stop paying for it, especially in the case of fuzzy search results.
2. Technical headaches. Customers complaining about fuzzy search results (intended for humans) not being predictable to a computer is simply a nightmare. At best, it causes downtime. At worst, it loses customers.
3. Continued development. Keeping track of a single session which searches multiple times for a specific address and eventually chooses one (the vast majority of use cases) can be a serious help for machine learning algorithms or even just observing repeated patterns and using it to improve the service.